# Jest database test not terminating with testcontainers

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, testing

I am trying to test my database in my Node application (Typescript). I am using Postgres 15 and Testcontainers to test my database. My code works fine manually and my clients are being released, but for some reason my tests don't terminate.

I want to test the `createUser` method which uses `getUserById`, which also uses `getTagsByUserId`.

```
    async createUser(user: User): Promise<User> {
        let client: PoolClient | undefined
        try {
            client = await DatabaseConnection.getClient()
            await client.query('BEGIN')
            const res = await client.query(this.CREATE_USER_QUERY, [user.username, user.password, user.nickname, user.email, user.dateOfBirth, user.pending])
            const userId = res.rows[0].user_id
            user.userId = userId
            if (user.tags) {
                for (const tag of user.tags) {
                    await client.query(this.CREATE_TAGS_QUERY, [userId, tag.toString()])
                }
            }
            await client.query('COMMIT')
            return await this.getUserById(userId)
        } catch (e) {
            if (client) await client.query('ROLLBACK')
            throw e
        } finally {
            if (client) await client.release()
        }
    }


    async getUserById(userId: string): Promise<User> {
        let client: PoolClient | undefined
        try {
            client = await DatabaseConnection.getClient()
            const res = await client.query(this.SELECT_USER_BY_ID_QUERY, [userId])
            const user: User = {
                dateOfBirth: res.rows[0].date_of_birth,
                email: res.rows[0].email,
                nickname: res.rows[0].nickname,
                password: res.rows[0].password,
                pending: res.rows[0].pending,
                private: res.rows[0].private,
                tags: [],
                userId: res.rows[0].user_id,
                username: res.rows[0].username
            }
            user.tags = await this.getTagsByUserId(userId)
            return user
        } catch (e) {
            throw e
        } finally {
            if (client) await client.release()
        }
    }

    private async getTagsByUserId(userId: string): Promise<Tag[]> {
        let client: PoolClient | undefined
        try {
            client = await DatabaseConnection.getClient()
            const res = await client.query(this.GET_TAGS_QUERY, [userId])
            return res.rows.map(row => row.user_tag)
        } catch (e) {
            throw e
        } finally {
            if (client) await client.release()
        }
    }
```

In `DatabaseConnection` I have a Client Pool. With `getClient` i return a Client from the pool.

This is my test:

```
import {UsersRepository} from "../../main/repository/users.repository";
import {Tag, User} from "../../main/schema/types";
import {Pool, PoolClient} from "pg";
import {
    TestContainer,
    StartedTestContainer,
    PostgreSqlContainer, Wait, StartedPostgreSqlContainer
} from "testcontainers";
import {DatabaseConnection} from "../../main/repository/DatabaseConnection";

const fs = require('fs')

jest.useFakeTimers()

const initSqlScript = fs.readFileSync('./sql/init.sql').toString()


describe('User Repository tests', () => {

    const port: number = process.env.DB_PORT ? +process.env.DB_PORT : 5432
    let pool: Pool
    let container: StartedPostgreSqlContainer

    beforeAll(async () => {
        container = await new PostgreSqlContainer("postgres:15")
            .withDatabase(process.env.POSTGRES_DB || 'test')
            .withUsername(process.env.POSTGRES_USER || 'test')
            .withPassword(process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD || 'test')
            .withExposedPorts(port)
            .start();
        pool = new Pool({connectionString: container.getConnectionUri()})
        const client = await pool.connect()
        await client.query(initSqlScript) // initializes my database
        await client.release()
        await DatabaseConnection.changeConnection(container.getConnectionUri()) // sets the connection for my DatabaseConnection to the test container
    })

    const userRepository = new UsersRepository()

    const originalUser: User = {
        dateOfBirth: "01-01-2000",
        email: "test",
        nickname: "test",
        password: "test",
        username: "test",
        pending: true
    }

    afterEach(async () => {
        await userRepository.clear()
    })

    it('should create a user in DB and return user with ID', async () => {
        const createdUser = await userRepository.createUser(originalUser)
        expect(createdUser.username).toBe(originalUser.username);
        expect(createdUser.email).toBe(originalUser.email);
        expect(createdUser.nickname).toBe(originalUser.nickname);
        expect(createdUser.password).toBe(originalUser.password);
        expect(createdUser.dateOfBirth).toBe(originalUser.dateOfBirth);
        expect(createdUser.pending).toBe(originalUser.pending);
        expect(typeof createdUser.userId).toBe("string")
    });
})
```

However, when i run my test, it does not terminate. I have checked the database and the user is created. I have also tried just returning the user object i have as input instead of getting the user from the database, but that also does not work.

I am logging any connections to my pool and it only says 1 idle connection and no active connections. When debugging, all of my clients are released.

Also, it works when I just use my local database, but I don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out on my own! I configured Jest to use fake timers because I read somewhere that this would help with timeout exceptions. Little did I know that this was causing my problems!